# Error: Path entry 'axis.jar' does not map to a real path. Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1

Tags: command-line-interface, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, picocli

I am attempting to build a native image for my picocli application using GraalVM, and I am encountering an error:

> Error: Path entry 'axis.jar' does not map to a real path.
> Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1

I used the following command  : `native-image -jar commandline-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: if your application has a dependency on axis.jar, you may need to add that to the classpath when building a native image. The docs for native-image may have more details.